# How to set a custom environment variable in EMR to be available for a spark Application

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, apache-spark, environment-variables, emr

I need to set a custom environment variable in EMR to be available when running a spark application.

I have tried adding this:

```
                   ...
                   --configurations '[                                    
                                      {
                                      "Classification": "spark-env",
                                      "Configurations": [
                                        {
                                        "Classification": "export",
                                        "Configurations": [],
                                        "Properties": { "SOME-ENV-VAR": "qa1" }
                                        }
                                      ],
                                      "Properties": {}
                                      }
                                      ]'
                   ...
```

and also tried to replace "spark-env with `hadoop-env`
but nothing seems to work.

There is [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=223617) answer from the aws forums. but I can't figure out how to apply it.
I'm running on EMR 5.3.1 and launch it with a preconfigured step from the cli: `aws emr create-cluster...`

Answer (score 11):

Add the custom configurations like below JSON to a file say, `custom_config.json`

```
[   
  {
   "Classification": "spark-env",
   "Properties": {},
   "Configurations": [
       {
         "Classification": "export",
         "Properties": {
             "VARIABLE_NAME": VARIABLE_VALUE,
         }
       }
   ]
 }
]
```

And, On creating the emr cluster, pass the file reference to the `--configurations` option

```
aws emr create-cluster --configurations file://custom_config.json --other-options...
```

Comment: This should be the exact same thing as what I did in the question, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, but within a file.

Comment: Sounds like a bug if Its true. Didn't tried it yet but are you sure this is what actually made the difference ??? because when I look at the EMR UI under configuration (with the version from the question)I can see my variable is set.. Its just that the spark app can't

Comment: Basically, AWS' EMR does not distribute spark-env.sh to worker nodes. Google's DataProc does. YARN is a sort-of hacky way of getting environmental variables in, though. Consider just passing them as app arguments into your spark job.

Answer (score 5):

For me replacing **spark-env** to **yarn-env** fixed issue.

Comment: the spark-env.sh file seems to get filled in by EMR, but maybe it doesn't get executed or something? Anyways, using yarn-env does seem to work. Maybe it's because we're running YARN, not spark directly?

Comment: Basically, AWS' EMR does not distribute `spark-env.sh` to worker nodes. Google's DataProc does. YARN is a sort-of hacky way of getting environmental variables in, though. Consider just passing them as arguments into your spark job.

Answer (score 1):

Use classification yarn-env to pass environment variables to the worker nodes.

Use classification spark-env to pass environment variables to the driver, with deploy mode client. When using deploy mode cluster, use yarn-env.

Answer (score 1):

For EMR 6.11.0, and running YARN in cluster mode, I had to use spark-defaults as per [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#environment-variables).

Example of custom configurations JSON below, setting two environment variables MY_ENV_VAR and ANOTHER_ENV_VAR.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark-defaults",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.driver.port": "999",  # example of other configs
      "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.MY_ENV_VAR": "value",
      "spark.yarn.appMasterEnv.ANOTHER_ENV_VAR": "another_value",
    }
  }
]
```