# What is the standard practice to add custom environmental variables to an AWS EMR?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-emr

- Unlike Elastic Beanstalk , AWS EMR doesn't have any facility to add / delete custom environment variables.

A. If I do it with the config file approach , how can i do if i want to add a new environment variable in an already present and running cluster ?

`aws emr create-cluster --configurations file://custom_config.json`

In this case , what if I want to add the env variable after the cluster creation ?

B.Is it correct to use steps to inject environment variable and is it possible to with steps ?

Am sure injecting environmental variables is a very common use-case, would like to know the best practice of doing it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would like to comment on the different approaches we have, based on reading out the AWS EMR documentation and talking to people.

1. AWS EMR as of date ( june -2019 )doesn't have a way to add environment variables that can be added just like configurations in elastic beanstalk.
2. We can take a look at  two approaches-

a. Add via the **config during cluster creation** ::

> aws emr create-cluster --configurations file://custom_config.json

[Refer ::
[How to set a custom environment variable in EMR to be available for a spark Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42395020/how-to-set-a-custom-environment-variable-in-emr-to-be-available-for-a-spark-appl) ]

Drop-back with this approach is that once cluster is created we wouldn't be able to do this via modify cluster.

b. Use **bootstrap action** option available in list-cluster view of AWS EMR.

```
 --bootstrap-actions Path=s3://mybucket/filename",Args=[arg1,arg2]
```

Though this also needs to be specified during cluster creation, we can change this file anytime. 
 For the change to get reflected - 
we need a cronjob maintained in master node to periodically run this script in all nodes.
When a new node is spawned for autoscale up , the modified values will be pushed to these newly created instances automatically.

Yeah, these are kind of work-around approaches.But these seem to the currently available ways apart from logging to each instance and setting the environment variables manually.

Please feel free to comment on any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Make the environment variable part of the udf.

Example code for a driver, for example in a loop:

```
envvar_foo_value = ... # read from S3, database, whatever

@series_udf(return_type=LAST_INTERACTOR_SPARK_RETURN_TYPE)
def env_var_aware_udf(arg1, arg2):
    os.environ["FOO"] = envvar_foo_value
    return actual_udf(arg1, arg2)

.. do something with env_var_aware_udf ...
```